# twilio get number of queued SMS

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I'm new to twilio.
Is there a way of getting the number of queued SMS directly from twilio?
In the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms#list-get-filters), it seems like there are some filters that twilio provides, but not for the queued SMS.
Does anyone have idea how to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can use the status attribute of a message to check whether the status is `queued`, `sending`, `sent`,`failed`, or `received`

Here's some sample code filtering only by the queued messages and returning its number. Other properties can be found [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms#list-get-filters).

```
$smsLog = $client->account->sms_messages->getPage(0, 5, array(
    'StartTime>' => '2015-04-01',
    'StartTime<' => '2015-05-01'
));

foreach ($smsLog->getItems() as $sms) {
    if($sms->status == "queued")
        echo $sms->to;
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: thanks, in the link you provide, there's no example of how to use the filter, can you give an example of how to get messages sent in one day?

Comment: Updated my answer with date filtering too. Just changes the dates to suit you.